# SAS Data Step: Concatenate string to variable on-the-fly

Tags: sas

I have the following sample data:

```
data have;
   input username $  betdate : datetime. winnings;
   retain username dateonly bedate result;
   dateOnly = datepart(betdate) ;
   format betdate DATETIME.;
   format dateOnly ddmmyy8.;
   datalines; 
    player1 12NOV2008:12:04:01 -10
    player1 12NOV2008:19:03:44 50
    player2 07NOV2008:14:03:33 -50
    player2 05NOV2008:09:00:00 -100
run;
PROC PRINT; RUN;
proc sort data=have;
   by username betdate;
run;
data want;
   set have;
    by username dateOnly betdate;   
   retain username dateonly bedate winnings winner resulthistory;
   if winnings > 0 then winner = 'W';
   if winnings <= 0 then winner = 'L';
   if first.winlose then resulthistory=winner;
   else if first.betdate then resulthistory=resulthistory||winner;
 PROC PRINT; RUN;
```

I want a cumulative result history in the last column. For player1, this will be 'WL'; for player2 it should be 'LL'. I've declared the resulthistory variable in the second data step, but can't seem to concatenate the new result onto the resulthistory variable if it's the same username. Is the problem that I'm working with a string variable or that I'm trying to reference something from a previous row?

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues- firstly, the concatenation action (`resulthistory=resulthistory||winner`) was padded with blanks, meaning that "winner" was chopped off the end of the string

There was also a non-existent variable (winlose), a typo (bedate), and an unnecessary retain statement in first data step.  See updated code below:

```
data have;
  input username $ betdate : datetime. winnings;
  dateOnly = datepart(betdate);
  format betdate DATETIME.;
  format dateOnly ddmmyy8.;
datalines;
player1 12NOV2008:12:04:01 -10
player1 12NOV2008:19:03:44 50
player2 07NOV2008:14:03:33 -50
player2 05NOV2008:09:00:00 -100
run;

proc sort data=have;
  by username dateonly betdate;
run;
data want;
  set have;
  format resulthistory $5.;
  by username dateOnly betdate;
  retain resulthistory;
  if winnings > 0 then winner = 'W';
  else if winnings <= 0 then winner = 'L';
  if first.dateonly then resulthistory=winner;
  else resulthistory=cats(resulthistory,winner);
run;
PROC PRINT; RUN;
```

Comment: Great stuff. I changed `if first.dateonly then resulthistory=winner;` to `if first.username then resulthistory=winner;` so that it was a result history for each player.

Comment: Enjoy.. Note that you will need a longer format for the resulthistory variable if you want more than 5 results :-)

Comment: How can I put each subsequent result in a new column i.e. firstBetResult, secondBetResult etc. So I can then group them in a PROC Tabulate to look at the average win on firstBet, secondBet etc.

Comment: proc sort data=want; by username dateonly;
proc transpose data=want out=want2;
by username dateonly;
var winner;
run;